# ajax call when something else is happening in the background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-1.8.7

I am trying to display the progress percentage when i upload a file and unzip it. I am using ruby-zip to unzip the file. While unzipping I increment the counter and store it in database. I have a form like

```
<% form_tag '/unzip', :multipart => true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag "zipfile", :size => 12 %> 
  <button class="add_button" type="submit" value="Add"> Add </button>
<% end %>
<div class="progress">
</div>
```

In `unzip` action there is everything that does unzipping and storing the value in database. Now, I would like to update the `.progress div` every 2 seconds or so. First, I tried to make ajax call when the button is clicked and call another method that gets this progress. But I was not successful because, this simple code below was giving me error.

```
<script>
$(".add_button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/get_progress", 
    method: "POST"
  })
})
</script>
```

In get_progress method, I just take out the value from the database like

```
def get_progress
  @progress = Progress.last.value
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

For simple checking purpose, I just do `console.log("rendered")` in the `get_progress.js.erb`. But this never gets called as there is error message before it. But, I checked and the ajax call is making request to `get_progress`.

But the problem is, I am getting error in `xhr.send((s.hasContent && s.data) || null)` in jquery1.6.3 line number 7948. I think I am getting this error because this page is redirected somewhere else during the ajax call and there is another request going on while I make the call as it is obvious that I have another action called when the form gets submitted.

When I print out the error on ajax call by doing:

```
error:function(xmlHTTPRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
  console.log(xmlHTTPRequest);
}
```

I am getting this:

```
Object {readyState = 0 ,status = 0 ,statusText = "error" }
```

I think my problem is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023867/jquery-xmlhttprequest-error). But, the answer presented here did not solve my issue.

Is there any way I can solve this issue? I hope the question is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me when I changed the ajax call from a `post` to a `get`.

View:

```
Progress:
<div id="progress">
</div>

<br />

<button class="add_button" type="submit" value="Add"> Add </button>
<script>
$(".add_button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/get_progress", 
    method: "get",
    dataType: "script"
  })
})
</script>
```

Controller:

```
def get_progress
  @progress = Progress.last.value
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

get_progress.js.erb:

```
$("#progress").text("<%= @progress.to_s %>");
```

Some obvious things to check:

- You have added the correct route for "/get_progress" with a "get" action
- JQuery is installed and working
- That the code in get_progress.js.erb is correct. If the JS and the embedded rails logic are not working properly, often it looks like "nothing is happening". Start with something simple like the above...

P.S. To run it in loop:

```
function updateProgress() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/get_progress", 
        method: "get",
        dataType: "script"
      });
}

// Set the function above to run every 2 seconds
var i = setInterval(updateProgress, 2000);
```

And update get_progress.js.erb:

```
$("#progress").text("<%= @progress.to_s %>");
var checkprogress = <%= @progress.to_i %>;
if (checkprogress == 100) {
   // Stop the function running. Should add clearInterval to error handling of ajax also
   clearInterval(i);
}
```

**Edit**

If there is some kind of conflict between the submit of the unzip action and retrieving the progress, I would recommend that you make the unzip submit asynchronous, using [remotipart](https://github.com/leppert/remotipart). Then change the form for unzip to:

```
<% form_tag '/unzip', :html => { :multipart => true }, :remote => true do %>
```

and add a `create.js.erb` file with `<%= remotipart_response do %>` as per the remotipart readme. I would still recommend that the get_progress ajax call is a get method.

Comment: The ajax call alone is working fine. The problem is with when something is happening along with ajax call. Like I said, when the progress is being taken out, the progress table is also getting updated. This part is done by the unzip method that is the action of the form!

Comment: @SadikshaGautam I would then recommend that the unzip submit is asynchronous - see edited answer.

Comment: @SadikshaGautam did this work for you? Do you need any more information?

Comment: yeah i made the unzip method asynchronous as well. Your answer is correct according to the question. But I would like to run these 2 ajax calls in parallel. :)